# IllegalArgumentException appeared when not supposed to

Tags: java

```
public class StringToPhoneNumberConverter implements Converter<String, PhoneNumberModel> {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{3,4})-(\\d{7,8})$");
    public PhoneNumberModel convert(String source){
        if(!StringUtils.hasLength(source)){
            //if "source" is empty, return null
            System.out.println("dsads");
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("dqwdwwdqwq");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
        if(matcher.matches()){
            //If it matches, start converting
            PhoneNumberModel phoneNumber = new PhoneNumberModel();
            phoneNumber.setAreaCode(matcher.group(1));
            phoneNumber.setPhoneNumber(matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("dsads");
            return phoneNumber;
        }else{
            System.out.println("dsadsqqdwqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
            //If it doesnt match throw an exception
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Failed to change the string to a phone number. The format is supposed to be [010-12345678], not [%s]", source));
        }
    }
}
```

The method threw an IllegalArgumentException when I do convert("dsadsdwqdwqqqqqqqqqqqq"). When I put the code that threw the exception when testing, I found exception message in the console. Sorry for me poor English.

Comment: Please insert the code in the question, not as an image!

Comment: This is not a plain Java question, add a tag with the framework you are using and that contains the Converter interface.

Answer (score 0):

If your input not matching to the expression **"^(\\d{3,4})-(\\d{7,8})$"**, always IllegalArgumentException should be thrown.

Irrespective of you are calling function from a test or running the program from command line.

Please share calling function code for more clarification.